# UIDevice currentDevice's "orientation" always null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, uidevice, interface-orientation

As per the title. 
Calling [[UIDevice currentDevice] BeginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications] has no effect.

DidRotateToInterfaceOrientation etc events are working fine, but I need to be able to poll the device orientation arbitrarily.

How can I fix/do this?

The long story:
I have a tab application with a navigation controller on each tab. The root view of tab number one is a graph that goes full screen when the orientation changes to landscape; however this needs to be checked whenever the view appears as the orientation change could have occurred elsewhere, so I was hoping to poll the orientation state whenever this view appears.

Answer (score 9):

UIDevice's notion of orientation seems to be only available on actual devices. The simulator seems to always return 0 here, regardless of whether the notifications have been enabled as the docs suggest. Irritatingly inconvenient, but there you go.

I find this works fine on the actual device:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    NSLog(@"orientation: %d", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Comment: Yep, just wasted 2h trying to figure out what was wrong but indeed it was just the simulator. All working fine on the device.

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] does not work if the user has locked his device orientation from the Springboard. orientation is always the last value, and there are no notifications for changes.

Comment: UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
this alternative worked for me

Answer (score 2):

seems like a silly question, but isn't it

> beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications

( lower case b )
...

Answer (score 2):

If you check `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` in `- (void)viewDidLoad` you will always get nil.

Check it in **`- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)`**animated method and you

Comment: "...you will always get `nil`".  Is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

this is as per iMeMyself said in the comments above - this samed me a lot of time and I think is the right answer so I wanted to highlight it here:

```
UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
{
   //do stuff here
}
else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
{
//or do stuff here
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, but shouldnt it be `UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation=[....` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] give you the current orientation state? You could check for this in your viewWillAppear method of the view controller that wants to poll.

Edit: Other than that, there are various ways to get the current orientation, such as using the statusBarOrientation property in UIApplication, or interfaceOrientation property in UIViewcontroller.

Comment: Looks like you didn't read the question. He's saying that method is returning NULL even though he's calling beginGeneratingOrientationNotifications.