# changing view controller when the device orientation changes

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation

Im making an ios app in xcode 4 and I need a way of changing what is displayed on the screen when the device orientation changes.

does anyone know how to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need to check first how to detect if the device orientation changes
see here: [how to detect orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122149/detecting-ios-uidevice-orientation)

then on the example on the link, you should know ho to change the view which is displayed on the screen. You can do it by using methods such as addSubview, presentModalViewController, pushViewController(for NavigationController)
eg:

- [self presentModalViewController:aView animated:YES];
- [self addSubview:aView];
- [self.navigationController pushViewController:aView animated:YES];