# Detect iPhone orientation event if UISupportedInterfaceOrientations set to portrait only?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, orientation

Is it possible in iOS to listen to changes in orientation/know the device current orientation, even if UISupportedInterfaceOrientations is set to portrait only, in the info.plist?

(My objective was to catch the event to change a text in the UI.)

Sincerely,

Jery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, even if set to portrait only, you can still listen for change and set actions accordingly.

Here's a link to a question that already has this answer.

[Detecting IOS UIDevice orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122149/detecting-ios-uidevice-orientation)

Hope this helps