# iOS >> Get Current Visible View / Window Size When Changing Orientation

Tags: ios, size, screen-orientation

Where can I get, programmatically, the current visible View / Window size?

especially relevant when changing orientation.

e.g. for Retina 4, I wish to get:

- Upon **Portrait**: 'h = 568.00, w = 320.00'.
- Upon **Landscape**: 'h = 320.00, w = 568'.

I've tried several elements and always get the same values (no matter what the orientation is):

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
[UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode.size;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.bounds.size;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use

> UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.height

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UIDevice * device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
switch(device.orientation)
   {
       case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
       /* start special animation */
       break;

       case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
       /* start special animation */
       break;

       default:
       break;
   };
```

see this for more information : [Detecting iOS UIDevice orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122149/detecting-ios-uidevice-orientation)

Comment: Thanks, Dev138, but that wasn't the issue... The issue is VIEW SIZE, i.e. HEIGHT and WIDTH. I'm looking for the property / method / object that holds the VISIBLE SIZE VALUES.

Comment: if you know the orientation can't you know if to switch height with width or not ?

Comment: I can... But I was wondering if there's any available variable, anywhere, that simply holds these values. Of course, I can retrieve the DEVICE, SCREEN SIZE and the ORIENTATION and calculate it manually for any given possibility (Retina 3.5 / Retina 4 / iPad / <iPhone 6 ratio when available> over Portrait / Landscape), but I thought that it might already exist somewhere in Apple's Objects...