# Different UITableViewCell for Portrait and Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Can we use a different TableViewCell for tableview when the device is in portrait mode and different TableViewCell when device turns to landscape mode?

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView` instead, and handle vertical and horizontal in different modes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure.

You can use the below lines of code to check for the current orientation and then decide which cell to use in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {
    //first cell
} else {
    //second cell
}
```

I think you would also need a trigger point for your table view to reload it's cells.

You can override the below method and then call the reloadData method whenever needed.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
}
```

Comment: it displays the landscape mode cell when the app launches and I have to rotate the device to landscape and portrait to get the portrait cell dequeued.

Comment: var cell = UITableViewCell()
        
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomerTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
            //cell.textLabel?.text = "hey how are yoy baby"
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "hbgusgdbdshfgdfjhdgjhmdngjsh"
        }
        return cell
 }      and then reloaded the cell in viewWillTransition method.

Comment: @ArshBhullar Regarding getting the correct orientation there are other answers too. Please check them once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452650/in-swift-how-to-get-the-device-orientation-correctly-right-after-its-launched

Answer (score 0):

like above, butfunc didRotate is deprecated, instead use

```
viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
               with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```