# How to detect orientation, if screen is locked in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

My application works in both orientation(portrait and landscape) but one of the screen is locked in portrait mode. But I have to set one value in Rotation variable for that particular screen. But I did not find orientation. 
So I want to find orientation.
I'm using this below code for lock my screen in portrait mode and it will work.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I'm using this below method to detect orientation but this will not called.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationland");

    }
}
```

Comment: You can see reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122149/detecting-ios-uidevice-orientation

Answer (score 1):

You can  detect orientation, if screen is locked in portrait mode. The easy way is "CoreMotion". The code snippet is below.

1-) Firstly, you should add CoreMotion freamework to Build Settings
[image]

2-) import CoreMotion freamework

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

3-) added property just like below.

```
    @interface BaseGeneralViewController (){
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientationLast, orientationAfterProcess;
    CMMotionManager *motionManager;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientationNew;

}
```

4-) we are created method to initialize

```
 - (void)initializeMotionManager{
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .2;
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = .2;
    
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                                [self outputAccelerationData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                            }
                                        }];
}
```

5-) declare outputAccelerationData method

```
    - (void)outputAccelerationData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration{
    
    if (acceleration.x >= 0.75 && orientationLast != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        [self callQRCodePayment:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }
    else if (acceleration.x <= -0.75  && orientationLast != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        [self callQRCodePayment:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }
    else if (acceleration.y <= -0.75) {
        //orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        //NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
    else if (acceleration.y >= 0.75) {
        //orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        // Consider same as last time
        return;
    }
    
    if (orientationNew == orientationLast)
        return;
    
    orientationLast = orientationNew;
}
```

6-) call initialize method in viewDidload

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeMotionManager];
}
```

you can see detail post[change Oriantation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116145751/http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2015/11/detect-device-rotation-even-when-rotation-lock-is-on.html)

Answer (score -1):

here are methods to detect orientation `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait`

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
     // code here for landscape orientation      
}

// And

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
    // code here for Portrait orientation       
 }
```

Comment: so what will you do after find the orientation after-all you locked the device orientation in portrait mode so you well knew about it now go ahead and set the variables value accordingly ..

Comment: Yeah I know that. But my `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method not called because my screen is locked in Portrait mode. @vaibhav

Comment: `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method called when user rotate screen and you locked it earlier now you can set the value you want to set ..