# Detecting iOS orientation change instantly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, orientation, gyroscope

I have a game in which the orientation of the device affects the state of the game. The user must quickly switch between Landscape, Portrait, and Reverse Landscape orientations. So far I've been registering the game for orientation notifications via:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

But it is far too slow - there seems to be about a second delay between rotating the phone and the notification actually being fired. I need a way to INSTANTLY detect changes in the device's orientation. I have tried experimenting with the gyroscope, but am not yet familiar enough with it to know whether or not it is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Here you go,Use this  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559652/how-do-i-detect-the-orientation-of-the-device-on-ios).Please let me know if any doubt.

Comment: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/detect-orientation-event very nice article

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That *delay* you're talking about is actually a filter to prevent false (unwanted) orientation change notifications.

For **instant** recognition of device orientation change you're just gonna have to monitor the accelerometer yourself.

Accelerometer measures acceleration (gravity included) in all 3 axes so you shouldn't have any problems in figuring out the actual orientation.

Some code to start working with accelerometer can be found here:

[How to make an iPhone App – Part 5: The Accelerometer](http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-5-the-accelerometer/)

And this nice blog covers the math part:

[Using the Accelerometer](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/basic-sensors-in/9781449309480/ch04.html)

Comment: UIAccelerometer is deprecated and replaced by Core Motion

Comment: Second link is broken.

Answer (score 144):

Add a notifier in the `viewWillAppear` function

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}
```

---

The orientation change notifies this function

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
   [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}
```

---

which in-turn calls this function where the moviePlayerController frame is orientation is handled

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    switch (orientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        { 
        //load the portrait view    
        }

            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
        //load the landscape view 
        }
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown:break;
    }
}
```

---

in `viewDidDisappear` remove the notification

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

---

I guess this is the *fastest u can have changed the view as per orientation*

Comment: Don't forget [super viewWillAppear:animated] and [super viewDidDisappear:animated] in case of copy paste like real programmers do.

Comment: Note : UIDeviceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.

Answer (score 20):

Why you didn`t use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

?

Or you can use this

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Or this

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Hope it owl be useful )

Comment: These methods will NOT be called automatically on child view controllers.

Comment: These methods are deprecated now.

Answer (score 12):

For my case handling `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` was not good solution as it is called more frequent and `UIDeviceOrientation` is not always equal to `UIInterfaceOrientation` because of (FaceDown, FaceUp).

I handle it using `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`:

```
//To add the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangeOrientation:)

//to remove the
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

 ...

- (void)didChangeOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try making your changes in:

`- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {}`

The code will run at every orientation change as the subviews get laid out again.

Answer (score 5):

@vimal answer did not provide solution for me. It seems the orientation is not the current orientation, but from previous orientation. To fix it, I use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
}
```

Then

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation) orientation { ... }
```

With this code I get the current orientation position.