# UIDocumentInteractionController disappears after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share data with other apps on device

```
 self.docInteraction = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageAttachFile];
 self.docInteraction.delegate = self;
 [self.docInteraction presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView: self.view animated: YES ];
```

It works nice, but it disappears after device rotation. What is the reason of it and how to fix this?

Comment: I had problems using `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero` on iOS 6. Replacing `CGRectZero` by a "real" rectangle or using `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:` worked better.

Comment: And i have no bar buttons? Yes it writes that presenting from rect will be deprecated, but i think the problem that it disappears is not connected with presenting method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be *UIDocumentInteractionController*'s default behaviour, which I'm also looking how to override.
But a work around I did was detect device' orientation change by one of the methods listed here:
[Detecting iOS orientation change instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085990/detecting-ios-orientation-change-instantly)
and again present your self.docInteraction on rotation.

Also if you intend to use **presentOptionsMenuFromRect** instead of **presentOpenInMenuFromRect** someday in future, you'll also have to separately handle same positioning issue with the **[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController]**.

Don't know whether it's the proper solution or not, but at least it'll serve your purpose :)