# Strange behaviour in iPad device has been inclined horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

when i incline horizontally an iPad device i obtain a strange behaviour.
The notification:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "MySelector", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

has been triggered and invoke "MySelector" causing unuseful ui update.
There is a way to avoid the triggering of my selector when my device has been horizontally inclined?

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the following previously asked question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085990/detecting-ios-orientation-change-instantly) -- is that if you do not want such a notification to appear, then you will want to override the viewDidDisappear method and call removeObserver(). I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, since I had some trouble understanding your original question. Let me know if this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: Doing that will disable orientation flipping all together,  I believe the poster is saying if he has a device laying flat on a surface facing horizontal, and he lifts the screen up and it is still horizontal, it is still calling the orientationdidchange notification.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I didn't think about that being what the OP meant by the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call function in an if condition to ensure that the orientation changed.  This is pseudo code:

```
func MySelector
{
  if oldorientation != neworientation
  {
      do stuff
  }
}
```

If this code is still firing, then that means that the system is going to portrait then horizontal real quick,  and you may have to put in a small timer or something to double check the orientation.