# Swift rotate icons when iPad is in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, icons

Currently my App looks like this in portrait mode:
[image]

but when my iPad is in landscape mode I want my Icons look like this:
[image]

By now it looks like that in landscape mode:

[image]

So my questions is: How can I just rotate the Icons? I don't need something more just the icons should move

Comment: i don't get it. If you are using size classes in storyboard this will not even be a question. All views & images rotate properly.

Comment: yeah they rotate but that doesn't look like that

Comment: I edited my post now you see what it looks like now

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code to the viewDidLoad method: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotate), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`
and this is the function:

```
    func rotate(){
 if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
     self.takephoto.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
     self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
 } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight {
     self.takephoto.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
     self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
 } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
     self.takephoto.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(0))
     self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(0))
 } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
     self.takephoto.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
     self.recordButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with supporting just portrait mode. You can observe for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification in your controller like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086463/4209778

Then based on your orientation you can rotate your icons using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation by (+/-)90 degree.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller override `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and rote your images using: `imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))`

EG:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let isPortrait = size.height > size.width
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(isPortrait ? 0 : M_PI_2))
}
```