# How to know the current orientation of a iDevice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm doing an app for Mathematics lessons & exercices...

I have only coded the MainMenu, but I've got a problem.
Indeed, I would like to know the current orientation to set up my stuff.

However, I tried different ways to know the current orientation, but I didn't succeed :

```swift
if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait {
            NSLog("Portrait")

        }

        else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {
            NSLog ("Landscape")
        }
```

I also see this answer, but it's not working (or maybe I haven't understood well)  : [Getting device orientation in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796545/getting-device-orientation-in-swift) , bu

I would like to specify that I'm in UIViewController in the ViewDidLoad().

Thanks for your help ‍

Comment: Override function `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Answer (score 0):

I set up a little prototype app with a button which checks for device orientation changes when pressed. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620041-begingeneratingdeviceorientation) which hopefully helps further your project along.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let device = UIDevice.current

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        device.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    }

    @IBAction func orientation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if device.isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications {
            switch device.orientation {
            case .landscapeLeft:
                print("Landscape Left")
            case .portrait:
                print("Portrait")
            case .landscapeRight:
                print("Right")
            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                print("Upside down")
            case .unknown:
                print("Unknown")
            default:
                print("Else")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is overkill. The reason he isn't getting orientation is (actually he is getting UIDeviceOrientation.unknown) he is trying in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Agreed, but they did not appear to know the code so I wrote it out. Your comment above is also a much better way of getting notifications without requiring any user input.